# How do I save and IntArray in android studio?

Tags: java, android, integer

I have int [] gameState = {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2} (its for tictactoe) and as an assignment requirement I need to save the data if the screen is rotated. I understand the activity cycle and that the activity is destroy and rebuilt upon reloading the new layout. I see ways to savepreference int with .getInt but .getIntArray doesn't work the way I thought. If I need to dump my java I can. I just haven't seen anyone answer this question before.

i've tried:

```
    @Override
        protected void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState) {
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    // Write the variable with the key in the Bundle
        outState.putIntArray("gameState", gameState);
    }

    @Override
        protected void onRestoreInstanceState (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    // Restore our variable by key
        gameState = savedInstanceState.getIntArray("gameState");
   }`
```

Editing the onDestroy (bad practice but I wanted to try everything)
Editing the manifest for onDestroy (again bad practice)

Comment: There is no putIntArray or getIntArray on  Bundle.  There is a putIntArrayList and getIntArrayList.

Comment: @GabeSechan get/putIntArray doesnt cause a error but get/putIntArrayList does give an error saying that it can't be found in bundle.

Comment: Ah, ok, the putIntArray is on the base class Bundle extends.  My bad.

Comment: all good! Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The integer array gameState is initialized with default values.
The onSaveInstanceState method saves the array to the Bundle with the key "gameState".
The onRestoreInstanceState method restores the array from the Bundle.
The above example should be enough to persist the gameState across activity destruction and re-creation  due to screen rotation).

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

int[] gameState = {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        gameState = savedInstanceState.getIntArray("gameState");
    }
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putIntArray("gameState", gameState);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    gameState = savedInstanceState.getIntArray("gameState");
}
```

}

As you're dealing with screen rotation, it might be helpful to handle the restoration of the game state in onCreate as well, just in case onRestoreInstanceState is not called. As you can see in the example, the gameState is checked and possibly restored in onCreate.

Comment: Unless I've got a bigger oopsie somewhere else, adding the onCreate code did not restore the data.

Comment: Here are some points to check:

Data Type Mismatch: Ensure that gameState is indeed an integer array (int[]) and not some other data structure like ArrayList<Integer>.

Initialization: Make sure gameState is properly initialized before you save or restore it.

Logs and Debugging: Use logs to check if the methods are being called and if the data is being properly saved and restored.

Comment: i am looking now and it is int[] gameState={}, However checking the Log gives me a bunch of errors (Unable to Start activity) regarding the onCreate and trying to remove and load writable dex file "/data/data/com.example.tic_tac_toe/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes3.dex"

Comment: I cant find any of the files the errors are referencing

Answer (score -1):

Since `savedPreferences` are used only to **store indicators** (that help you load the preferred user settings on loading an activity) that is why the data types you can store are only primitive data types.

But if you still want to instantly store some data (any Object) into sharedPrefs you can convert them into Json String using [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) library

Obviously not the best practice but very convinient for begineers.